# Build array iterating over multiple indices in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, indices

I want to obtain the following result with a more elegant syntax

```
julia> collect(Iterators.flatten([[(x,y) for y in 1:x] for x in 1:3]))
6-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 1)
 (2, 1)
 (2, 2)
 (3, 1)
 (3, 2)
 (3, 3)
```

I tried something like `[(x,y) for y in 1:x, x in 1:3]` but I get `ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reverse the order of variables like this:

```
julia> [(x,y) for x in 1:3 for y in 1:x]
6-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 1)
 (2, 1)
 (2, 2)
 (3, 1)
 (3, 2)
 (3, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

I used to have also been struggled to remember the variable order. Until one day someone told me a *secret*: just treat the order of `for` loop in the list comprehension as usual except that the body is moved to the front.

For example, in *normal* order we write:

```
for x in 1:3
    for y in 1:x
        # do sth
    end
end
```

Now we move the body part to the front and we have `[ #= do sth =# for x in 1:3 for y in 1:x]`